# Use a .mcr memory card file in Mednaffen or Epsxe

Tags: emulation, ps1, epsxe

I want to finish a game that i had left unfinished from my childhood.
I downloaded a save game file 'ff8.mcr'.
Mednaffen places `.mcr` files in the directory `/sav`.

I placed the file there, started the game, but it was not recognized.

However, i noticed that the emulator had created two files in that directory:

```
Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.0.mcr
```

and

```
Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.1.mcr
```

I deleted all three files, renamed the original `ff8.mcr` to `Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.0.mcr` and restarted the game.

The saves were not recognized, and then i had three files in the /sav directory.

```
Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.0.mcr
```

and

```
Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.1.mcr
```

and

```
Final Fantasy VIII (USA) (Disc 3).1f10bae377ddeefe84e98b02a7b649b1.0.mcr.mcr
```

which was probably my original file, but Mednaffen now appended another extension at the end.

For Epsxe, i am equally lost. Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you very much!